# Is the overall model fit/significance always important? (multivariate multiple regression)

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis

I've read that it's important to report the overall fit of the model. I'm more interested in the individual relationships between IVs and DVs, but worried that the fact the overall model doesn't fit (pillai's trace/wilks' lambda non-significant) makes these relationships irrelevant, or something.

But a lot, perhaps the majority, of multivariate multiple regression papers I've come across don't seem to bother reporting the overall model fit/significance. Here's two:

https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/epdf/10.1177/1069072708318905

https://www.emerald.com/insight/content/doi/10.1108/JWL-06-2015-0052/full/pdf

To quote the entirety of the reporting of the regression in the first linked study:

> A simultaneous multivariate multiple regression analysis was conducted
> to examine whether Mexican orientation, Anglo orientation, college
> self-efficacy, and college outcome expectations predicted  Mexican
> American  high  school  students’ educational  aspirations  and
> expectations. Anglo orientation was found to be significant,
> Wilks’Λ=.87,F(2, 83) =6.08,p<.05,ηm=.13,where ηm represents the
> multivariate effect size. However, Mexican orientation, Wilks’s
> Λ=.94,F(2, 83) =2.51,p>.05,ηm=.05, college self-efficacy, Wilks’s
> Λ=.98,F(2, 83) =.85,p>.05,ηm=.02,  and  college  outcome
> expectations, Wilk’s  Λ=.98,F(2,  83) =.92,p>.05,ηm=.02, were not
> significant. Follow-up univariate analyses revealed that Anglo
> orientation had a sig-nificant  positive  relationship  with
> educational   aspirations,F(1,88) =10.06,p<.01,η=.11(where η
> represents the univariate effect size), and educational
> expectations,F(1,88) =9.58,p<.01,η=.10, for Mexican American high
> school students

No mention of overall model fit, how all IVs simultaneously explain the combined DVs. They just report the individual relationships. Weird, right? Maybe it's taken as a given that it won't fit, because some of their IVs were non-significant, but still, they could have mentioned it or performed another regression using the significant IVs to see if the overall model fit after removing them. Even when all IVs are significant in studies like this, they often don't seem to bother reporting the overall model fit.

When would it be appropriate for me to ignore the fact my overall model is non-significant, and just report the individual relationships?